# Are there other Mjölnirs?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir, asgardians

Apologies if this is a dumb question since I'm not a comic reader.

Are there other Asgardian relics similar to Mjölnir?  I.e. they are weapons or tools or other similar objects that have some kind of enchantments bestowing powers upon the wielder?

How are they similar and how do they differ?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Mjolnir is kind of special even for an Asgardian relic. It is forged from Uru which is only available on one of the nine realms, and is heavily enchanted by the All-Father himself. Most Asgardian relics will likely be of a lesser tier.

Comment: Is this question pertaining to just Norse Mythology or specifically to the Marvel Universe?

Comment: @kelzak:   If it were related to Norse Mythology, it would be off topic here.

Answer (score 8):

You don't even need the comics to find one answer, in the first series of Agents of SHIELD there is the Berserker staff which imbues its bearer with supernatural strength alongside amplifying rage and similar negative emotions. It differs from Mjölnir in that there doesn't seem to be any magical requirements to be able to wield it, although the mental effects take a toll on the user even after putting it down.

It was left hidden on earth after its original Asgardian bearer deserted, but is Asgardian in origin.

see http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker_Staff

I'd suspect there is plenty more examples in the comics, but I've not heavily read them. There are certainly similar non-Asgardian relics like the black knight's sword though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. A lot of them. There are even additional hammers from Thor-Like characters. Thunderstrike has a mace and Beta Ray Bill has its own hammer. It is called "Stormbreaker".

Comment: Put in some more details and some quotes and/or pictures and I'll give you a bountyyyy.

Answer (score 1):

As Talking Code mentioned there are a LOT of them.  Here's a pretty good [list](http://www.cbr.com/beyond-thors-mjolnir-the-15-greatest-asgardian-weapons/) of 15  Asgardian weapons with good references to the issues they first showed up in, a summary of the story of their first appearance and their powers/effects in the Marvel universe.

Besides Mjolnir Thor had also wielded another enchanted Uru metal weapon, Jarnbjorn.  This axe was also created by the same dwarves that crafted Mjolnir.
It didn't have any powers over the weather like Mjonlnir, but it was also indestructible, enchanted to be so sharp it could cut through virtually anything, including Celestial Armor after it was "blessed" with Thor's blood[Thor God of Thunder #18]. 
Also it could defend against attacks, even beams of energy